# File upload path issue

Tags: php, file-upload, file-permissions

`My server URL is = http://75.126.174.170/~grooplin`

I want to upload images into 'uploads/images/' folder in my public_html folder

But

```
$uploadfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/~grooplin/uploads/images";

is_dir($uploadfile) // returns false
```

While echoing

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];         // I got '/usr/local/apache/htdocs'
```

What will be the upload path for this?

Comment: Check is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/~grooplin/uploads/images/")

Comment: @JensonMJohn He is already doing that

Comment: What is a result of `is_dir('uploads/images');`?

Comment: @Sean Doe that returns true. But in many places $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is used. This is already finished project but server is changed now and got this issue. How will i solve without using this relative url

Comment: How will i get absolute path of this server dynamically?

Comment: What about `ini_set('doc_root', '/usr/local/apache/htdocs/~grooplin'); `? Are you sure your script is in this directory? If your current path does not work, try `/home/grooplin`

Answer (score 0):

> **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** >> The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

If your upload directory is within your document root you would need to define the path as such:

```
$uploadfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/images";

// OR

$uploadfile = "uploads/images";
```

Comment: $uploadfile = "uploads/images"; returns true. But in many places $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is used. This is already finished project but server is changed now and got this issue. How will i solve without using this relative url

Comment: First one $uploadfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/images"; returns false

Comment: @user2609417 In your virtual host file, define your document root to the appropriate path using the `DocumentRoot` entry. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

try with setting upload file path to:

```
$uploadfile = "./uploads/images/";
```

Comment: $uploadfile = "./uploads/images/"; returns true. But in many places $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is used. This is already finished project but server is changed now and got this issue. How will i solve without using this relative url